# How to solve trigonometric equations with an absolute value?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

To solve$$|\cos 2x|\geq|\sin x|,(x\neq \frac{n\pi}{2})$$

Taking cases doesn't seem efficient to me here and it is the only method I know to approach these problems.

Is there a better way to solve this? Perhaps squaring it?

Comment: You only need to take cases in the interval of $[-\pi,\pi]$ after which it is periodically repeating

Comment: @Empy2: this is said in the question.

Comment: You only need four cases:
$$
0\leq\sin x\leq \cos 2x\\
0\leq\sin x\leq -\cos 2x\\
0\leq-\sin x\leq \cos 2x\\
0\leq-\sin x\leq -\cos 2x
$$
It really isn't that much work.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan: $[0,\pi]$ is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Squaring and setting $t:=(\sin x)^2\ge0$, you need to solve$$(1-2t)^2\ge t$$

or
$$\bigg(t-1\bigg)\left(t-\frac14\right)\ge0.$$

The first factor cancels at $x=k\pi$ or is negative. The rest of the discussion reduces to

$$\sin^2x\le\frac14$$ or $$-\sin\frac\pi6\le\sin x\le\sin\frac\pi6.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Just a follow-up question since the maximum value of $|\sin x|$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ is it safe to say it is the minimum value of $|\cos 2x|$ in the context of my question?

Comment: @JustJohan: not at all, the two members vary simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I think I get it.